# Derivative of a function from first principle and normally ,yields different answers

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have a function 
$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2}), & x\neq 0 \\ 
0, & x =0
\end{cases}$$

and I want to take its derivative at $x=0$, by the first principal,
$$ f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ which would give me $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \sin(\frac{1}{h^2})-0}{h}$$ which is equal to $$\lim_{h \to 0} h \sin(\frac{1}{h^2}) = 0 $$

But if I take the normal derivative, I get$$ f'(x) = 2x \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})- \frac{2}{x} \cos(\frac{1}{x^2}),$$  which is not defined at $x=0$. 
Where am I wrong ??

Comment: The second derivative you calculated is the derivative for $x\ne0$. The one you did by first principal is the derivative for $x=0$.

Comment: @zbrads2 Why for x ≠ 0 , is it because it's not in the domain or I have cases , or in general is the second method not applicable if it is out of the domain??

Comment: The issue is that you used the definition of $f(x)$ for $x\ne0$ in order to compute the derivative everywhere. But actually, this only gives you the derivative of $f(x)$ for $x\ne0$.

Comment: @zbrads2 Oh Ok , Thanks a lot :)

Comment: In fact, the function $f$ you found is a standard example of a differentiable function whose derivative is not continuous (at $0$).

Answer (score 1):

When you tried to use the product rule for derivative $(gh)'=g'h+gh'$, you need $g$ and $h$ to be differentiable at the point in question.

You are trying to apply the product rule with $g(x)=x^2$ and $h(x)=\sin(1/x^2)$.  However, $h$ is not differentiable at $0$ (it is not even possible to define $h(0)$ so that it is continuous there), so you cannot use the product rule there.  For $x\neq 0$, both $g$ and $h$ are differentiable at $x$ and hence you can use the product rule.